# add description grid list on theme mobile shoppe

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i try to add "short description" on my category list of my products but nothing happend on  my list.phtml
i try on: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

in my lit view are there this code:
(and i copy this code to grid block but nothing happend)

```
 <div class="desc std">
                    <h1>test</h1>
                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes`, search for the `short_description` attribute, edit it and set the field `Used in product listing` to `Yes`. Reindex everything and it should work.
**[EDIT]**
Or you can simply use this:

```
<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription();?>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer with an other possible solution. If it's worth something. It worked for me. (both of them)

Comment: Do you know what "mobile shopper" run as list.phtml base or their own template?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'mobile shopper'?

Comment: this is my theme i use!